# RedirectToAction problems in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

RedirectToAction method doesn't work, can't solve it for the past 4 hours. Here is the code from the User controler:

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(UsersNew form)
{
    var user= new User();
    UserDB db = new UserDB();
    db.addUser(form.Username, form.Password, form.SchoolName, form.Country, form.City);
    return RedirectToAction("Home");
}
```

It says that there is no route registered like that, although it adds users to the database, so only redirect does not work. This is my routeConfig file:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute("Home", "", new { controller = "First", action = "FirstView" });
    routes.MapRoute("Register", "register", new { Controller = "Users", action = "Register" });
    routes.MapRoute("About", "about", new { Controller = "About", action = "About" });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Home` is not an action, it's route. You should use [RedirectToRoute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470174(v=vs.118).aspx).

```
return RedirectToRoute("Home");
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept it as an answer, if it solved your problem to guide others.